# Partial com Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, lado-do-cliente, partialview

Se eu criar uma Partial dessa forma abaixo "dada como exemplo":

```
  <script>
       //Codigos C# Meus documentos..
       //Codigos Javascript...
  </script>
```

... e dentro dessa partial conter códigos c#, essa partial juntamente com codigos c# e javascript estarão rodando como client-side ou server-side ...

Comment: Código C# é **sempre** executado do lado *server*

Comment: Além disso, a *Partial View* por conter código server e também uma extensão particularmente processada pelo *server* (`.cshtml` por exemplo) acaba sendo renderizada do lado *server*, somente o `javascript` é executado todo no lado *client*

Comment: Ha Obrigado pela a resposta!